# Запрет экранирования символов в sql

Tags: sql

[image]

```
UPDATE `wp_ewwwio_images` 
SET `path`=REPLACE(`path`,('C:\OSPanel\domains\wordpress\') , '') 
WHERE `path` LIKE ('%C:\OSPanel\domains\wordpress\%')
```

sql воспринимает слэш как знак экранирования, что делать?

Comment: prepared statement ваше все

Comment: *что делать?* Читать [мануалы](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-literals.html) до полного понимания. И далее либо корректировать литералы, либо режим сервера.